# How to make a custom markup language/parser in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, parsing, codeigniter

I'm working on a custom CMS in Codeigniter and I'm trying to allow users to use custom tags instead of having to place HTML into posts.

For example, if a person is posting about a game and want to include a stylized button as a call to action, they would just type `[button=http://example.com]Play this game[/button]` instead of the HTML `<div class="action-button"><a href="http://example.com">Play this game</a></div>`

Obviously, this is a simple example. Some more complex things I'd like to do would be something like `[gallery=120]` which would include an image gallery with an ID of 120.

I've been searching and I haven't had much luck. I feel like there's another word for what I'm trying to do but it's just not coming to me, maybe that would yield better search results.

Any tips to get me going would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're just looking for a solution, and don't care about taking the time to learn how to implement this yourself, install a markdown parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you're looking for is **BBCode** (Bulletin Board Code).

As for parsing you could look at some forum apps and perhaps CI's template parser for inspiration. Like Jarrett already mentioned they mostly utilize `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()` functions. 
Something like `[gallery=120]` would be more advanced though.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be STRING and REGEX replace statements.

If your familiar with the CMS associated with CodeIgniter, that is, ExpressionEngine, it parses the templates using str_replace() and preg_replace().